# How would I go about UV mapping this object?

Tags: modeling, uv, lighting

I just modeled this object that I'm going to be using in a bathroom. I tried importing it into Unreal Engine but when I do the mesh becomes black after light building. People said I have to create a UV lightmap so I looked up tutorials but first I need to UV unwrap twice since Unreal Engine takes the second UV as the lightmap. I have no clue where to start UV mapping since the urinal part dips in. I understand the top sensor part since its just circles and spheres, but its the other part I'm confused about.

Object mode:

[image]
https://gyazo.com/788809e77f70e60108258f7820b38c36

Edit Mode:
https://gyazo.com/ecbdebe1bdebc22820bbe4fab8123176

Here's a view from the inside:
Object Mode:

[image]
https://gyazo.com/0ca128321a4e9b5726f2f4e6304865b0

Edit Mode:

[image]
https://gyazo.com/5e0349a89a71de55d54bad68987847f9

---

Can someone please just say where I should mark seems?

Comment: First, just try to make any flat surfaces one face. select one face on a flat surface and hit CTRL + SHIFT + ALT + F and then dissolve the selection by hitting X and then dissolve faces. This will make some things less complicated.

Comment: Ok thank you for that it did clear some room up and removed some vertices for space in the game. However, I still need help on what corners I should mark seems so I can unwrap it because of the part it dips in.

Comment: That would be easier if you hadn't used the bevel modifier yet.

Comment: I haven't yet. I only beveled where it curves like this:

https://gyazo.com/e2f87a90e9892bce2cc2c15db3ff1c87

Comment: You should be read the [The tutorial of UV Mapping](http://www.blendmuns.id) it may can help you. And you can look more and read more many tutorial in there, thanks

Answer (score -2):

Never mind everyone I did a UV Smart Project and it looks like this:

[image]

Would this be good for making the light map and stop the overlapping?

Comment: Please use the built in tool to post images so that they display as part of your post. Use the answer section for answers only, not to ask additional questions. To ask a new question please use http://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/ask

Comment: Can someone answer my question and I won't have to make a new answer for it to be at the top of the forums. Just a simple yes or no. Can a smart UV project be good for lightmapping and stop my mesh from being black when I build lighting\?

Comment: please reat the [help] section to understand how this site works. This is not a forum but a question and answer site.